# How to install libuuid on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, gearman

I'm trying to compile gearman-0.28 on Mac, but encountered the following error:

```
configure: error: Unable to find libuuid
```

I don't know how to install libuuid on Mac, my Mac is 10.7.2 version.
Any one can help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I got my Gearman - admittedly an earlier version - sorted on 10.6.8 using macports. Would that be any good?

Comment: which version of gearman are you using?

Comment: `port info gearmand` gives `gearmand @0.14, Revision 2 (sysutils, net, devel)`. I'm no macports expert however, so I don't know if it could be bumped up by my loading something newer.

Answer (score 18):

With [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/):

```
brew install ossp-uuid
```

Comment: ossp-uuid is not libuuid

Answer (score 9):

For those who are trying to install the `uuid` extension from PECL, the `ossp-uuid` and the `util-linux`'s `uuid` package shipped with Mac OSX will not work as they are out dated. You will need an updated version of uuid from `util-linux`. It is available on Homebrew.

```
brew install util-linux
```

But `util-linux` is a keg-only package and will not be symlinked to `/usr/local`. Hence you will have to specify the following path when prompted for uuid installation directory

```
/usr/local/opt/util-linux
```

For unattended installations, you can use

```
printf "/usr/local/opt/util-linux" | pecl install uuid
```

Comment: You saved my day. Thanks!

Comment: "Hence you will have to specify the following path when prompted for uuid installation directory" - how?

Comment: @blkpingu You will get a prompt asking for your uuid installation directory, You can just copy paste the path `/usr/local/opt/util-linux` and press enter.

Comment: for me the path was `/opt/homebrew/opt/util-linux`.

Answer (score 1):

Install mac port like

`sudo port install ossp-uuid`

`$configure --with-lib`

Answer (score 1):

As time goes by, it seems worthwhile to mention that libuuid has become part of macOS in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an up to date alternative to the `brew` or `mac ports` solutions, the following from [here](https://coderwall.com/p/t_sz3q/generate-uuid-at-shell-prompt) works great. You can also add the code to your `.zshrc` or `.bash_profile`

```
$ alias uuid="python -c 'import sys,uuid; sys.stdout.write(uuid.uuid4().hex)' | pbcopy && pbpaste && echo"

$ uuid
34469137412242129cd908e384717794
```