# How do I install libuuid with Homebrew on MacOS 11.1?

Tags: c, homebrew, uuid

I'm aware there is a macports libuuid package, however AFAIK it's not safe to use homebrew and macports on the same machine.

[This answer seems outdated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772151/how-to-install-libuuid-on-mac-os-x). I say that because when I use `brew install ossp-uuid` make doesn't like it, despite seeming to find `uuid.h`.

What is the current and up to date homebrew package to install `libuuid` on mac?

Alternatively, could one build `libuuid` from source and if yes, how?

Comment: for what programming language that library you would use?

Comment: adding a tag sorry

Answer (score 2):

I was made aware that libuuid is already part of macOS.

It was therefore enough to just add an OS specific include.

```c
#if __APPLE__
    #include <uuid/uuid.h>
#else
    #include <uuid.h>
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

I was porting an app from Linux to MacOS Monterey (could apply to 11.1 (Big Sur) as well).

The link was failing on libuuid, even though it compiled ok as on Linux.

I finally got my build to link, having 'homebrew install'ed ossp-uuid with homebrew version 3.6.4, under Monterey (12.5.1).

I first heard of ossp-uuid in this thread (thanks [blkpingu](/questions/tagged/blkpingu)).

I had tried several things before. It compiled ok, but did not link. brew install ossp-uuid fixed that (homebrew 3.6.4), and brew set up the requisite links to find the library under /usr/local/lib .

I left the source code as #include <uuid/uuid.h>, in this particular case.